# Updating Pager with PagedList and Javascript in Partial Views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, pagedlist

I have a view User which calls a partial view _TableWithPager:

```
    <div id="tableWithPagerId">
    @Html.Action("LoadUserTable","Controller", Model)
    </div>
```

In my Controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadUserTable(object model)
{
   PagedList userList = getUserList(bla bla bla)...
   return View("_TableWithPager", userList);
}
```

Inside of _TableWithPager, i have other partial view _TableUser and the pager of that table:

```
@model PagedList<user>
<div id="TableContainerId">
   @Html.Partial("_TableUser");
</div>
<div id="Paginator">
   @Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("LoadUserTable", new { page = page, /*more params...*/ }) )
</div>
```

I used javascript to get the click event of pager:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Paginator').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#TableContainerId').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It all works. However, if I click on the second page will be rendered in "TableContainerId" table div properly and the pager will not be updated. That's a problem. If I change the javascript to render in the "tableWithPagerId" div, the table will be updated and the pager, but I have to reload the javascript again.

Does anyone have any idea how can I solve this? I searched about putting javascript inside the partial view when it is loaded to load the script as well, but does not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Calling in partial view will not work. 
Some time after, I got a simple solution that works perfectly. Just call the javascript function after reload html data. like this:

```
function bind() {
    $('#Paginator').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#TableContainerId').html(result);
                bind(); // called this java script code again
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the specific answer of Marco I would like to suggest a general solution:

You can use this javascript library (which I wrote): https://github.com/pjbonestroo/PagedList

It solves the problem of reloading, pagination, etc, and is fully customizable. It includes documentation.

It also has some nice features like

- filtering and sorting (client- or server-side, as preferred)
- debouncing to prevent too many refreshes
- customizable buttons and styling, dependent on row-data
- easily add/remove event-listeners to rows (and get the row-data on triggering)

Note: using this library you won't use partial views anymore...

Just have a look, if you are still developing paginated lists in the browser.