# Add attribute to pagination url.action?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcrazor

I am trying to add attributes like `ID` into pagination so I can perform some actions in JS on behalf of that.

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ConfirmCases", new { page }))
```

when I tried to add it shows in the URL. Does anybody know how I can set an `ID` in this case?

any helps regarding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ConfirmCases", new { ID = ViewContext.ViewBag.CheckingAccountId, page, PageSize = Model.PageSize } ))
```

`ViewContext` needed to be added in order to get the ID from the `viewbag`... and also declared the id again in the controller.

**OR**
Using JQuery

```
<div id="Paginator">
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ConfirmCases", new { ID = ViewContext.ViewBag.CheckingAccountId, page, PageSize = Model.PageSize } ))
</div>
```

**Jquery Function**

```
function bind() {
    $('#Paginator').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#TableContainerId').html(result);
                bind(); // called this java script code again
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to detect that id in JS. when someone clicks on that then in JS I have to perform some actions before it hits to the controller.

Comment: Check my edited answer, For details, you get an idea from  this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769933/updating-pager-with-pagedlist-and-javascript-in-partial-views